# How to compare two table with duplicate key reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two worksheets, and there are many columns and rows inside.
The same key reference is " order number" with two worksheets.
But unfortunately, the order numbers are duplicate.
is there any way I can compare the two sheets in one sheet and one time?

Sheet A

```
ordernumber cost QTY    date ......
   A10       50   2   12/05/2018
   A18       20   2   12/05/2018
   A10       50   3   12/01/2018
   A18       20   10  12/02/2018
   A13       50   7   12/04/2018
```

Sheet B

```
ordernumber cost QTY    date ......
  A10        50   3    12/01/2018
  A13        50   7    12/04/2018
  A18        20   5    12/05/2018 
  A18        20   2    12/02/2018
```

compare sheet

```
ordernumber  QTYA     QTY B  GAPQTY
  A10          5       3      2
  A18         12       7      5
  A13         7        7      0
```

Comment: *the order numbers are duplicate* Use SUMIF() instead of single value obtained with VLOOKUP()...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Write this Array Formula in Cell `A2` of **Compare Sheet**, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill it down.

   ```
    {=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6), 0)), INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($A$1:A1, Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5), 0))), "")}
   ```
2. Enter this Array Formula in Cell `B2` of **Compare Sheet**, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & Fill down.

   ```
    {=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6=$A2)*(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6))}
   ```
3. Write this Formula in Cell `C2` of **Compare Sheet**,  finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill it down.

   ```
    {=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5=$A2)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$5))}
   ```
4. Finally in Cell `D2` of **Compare Sheet** write this Formula and fill down.

   ```
    =B2-C2
   ```

Comment: For 2.3.4 are ok, but 1. is not working well. each order duplicate two lines, why put 0 inside match here? and if I have more than 10000 rows, will it take lots of time? is there any way can use a pivot table or query?

Comment: @dorachen,, Zero with Match execute `Countif` to create Unique rows, and the screen shot is part of the active sheet I've worked with all working formulas before post here. Problem is at your end!  There are several methods but the suggested one in better and Faster,, could works for tons of rows.

Comment: I agree with you. Problem is in my side, I really don't know array but I try many times and it still not work. Below is my formula, sometimes three cells work but sometimes only two cells.  no idea why? =IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX('M10'!L:L,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A6,'M10'!L:L),0)),INDEX('All order'!A:A,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A6,'All order'!A:A),0))),"")  BTW, it really takes me lots of time to fix and save.

Comment: @dorachen, the mistake I found is that you committed mistake with `Countif data Range`,. I guess that you are using this Formula in Sheet `M10`. Write both `Countif` like this `COUNTIF($A$1:A1`, will solve the issue.

Comment: **Cont..** my suggestion is first try the exercise in smaller data range as I've shown then on the real Range.

Comment: Thanks, I put the COUNTIF($A$1:A1) in fist cell and this is the sixth cell, so it will become ($A$1:A6), but I try to practice in a small range and it works. Many thanks.

Comment: @dorachen ,,,again you are in wrong path,,, suppose you have written the formula in Cell `A2` then it will be `Countif($A$1:A1), finish the formula as shown and fill down,, and that's all.

Comment: **Cont,,** read the shown steps carefully and first try on small Range as I did !!